# how to calculate date range correctly using arrow in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have the small snippet of codes below, I am trying to calculate the number of days between **today** and **yesterday** using `arrow` and make sure the result is accurate.

```
import arrow

TODAY = arrow.now()

YESTERDAY = arrow.now().shift(days=-1)

result = TODAY - YESTERDAY

print("result: ", result)
print("number of days: ", result.days)
print("TODAY: ", TODAY)
print("YESTERDAY: ", YESTERDAY)
```

here is the result that i am getting:

```
result:  23:59:59.999912
number of days:  0     # this is because the result is not 24 but 23:59 instead... 
TODAY:  2022-05-16T11:54:03.332408+00:00
YEST:  2022-05-15T11:54:03.332496+00:00
```

Is there a better way that i am missing on how to achieve the above using `arrow` specifically?

Comment: how about doing `TODAY.shift(days=-1)` instead of `arrow.now().shift(days=-1)`? Why would you expect number of days equal to 1 between 2 dates that are **not** 1 day apart, but less?

Comment: you could change the ORDER of `TODAY = ....` and `YESTERDAY = ...` - then you will have 24.00:00.xxxxx instead

Comment: if you shift by 1 - why calculate the datediff at all ... you are shifting by 1

Comment: @JohnD Posted as an answer if you want to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing `TODAY.shift(days=-1)` instead of `arrow.now().shift(days=-1)`. This way your dates will be exactly 1 day apart, no matter how long execution of statements took.

Answer (score 1):

I ran it several times on my system and it always came up with

```
result:  1 day, 0:00:00
number of days:  1
TODAY:  2022-05-16T07:15:14.513011-05:00
YESTERDAY:  2022-05-15T07:15:14.513011-05:00
```

Does it get better on your machine if you change

```
YESTERDAY = arrow.now().shift(days=-1)
```

to this?

```
YESTERDAY = TODAY.shift(days=-1)
```

Comment: Running a simple for loop, ~6% of cases number of days is 0. (n = 100 000 sample size). With `TODAY.shift` it goes down to 0%.